# Access Magento session from external site

Tags: session, cookie, external, application

How do you log in an existing customer/user from external application or bypass his session after logging into `Magento` to other application?

Comment: What do you mean by "bypass his session"?

Comment: Once logged into the account under magento the user will be able to switch to another app and this other app will be able to keep his session and cookies from magento.

Comment: As long as the app runs under the same domain than there should be know issue accessing the session.

Comment: Ah ok thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way would probably be to create a Mage instance in your external code, as described [here](http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/09/run-magento-code-outside-of-magento/).

Once you have access to the Mage object, you can pull up the Customer session model and log a customer in that way.  In fact, on the page I linked, they point out a way to do just what you're looking for I believe:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');  
$customer->loadByEmail('some@email.address'); /* need a users email address */  
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');  
$session->start();
```